# Firefox 3.6: can't see characters in Find textbox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, find

After I upgraded to Firefox 3.6, I can't see text as I type it in into the Find text box.

For example, if I press Ctrl+F (or / or '), the characters that I type in don't appear until there's no match (Phrase not found). This is pretty annoying.

I'm on Windows 7 x64 Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close all Firefox windows, then run Firefox from the comamnd-line with:

```
firefox.exe -safe-mode
```

and see if the problem still occurs (safe-mode disables all extensions).

If the problem goes away in safe-mode, you should then run Firefox normally, but disable extensions one-by-one until you discover which extension is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I disabled the "Stylish" add-in and now Find works and so does Personas.